# Access users twitter, gmail and facebook notification

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, notifications, gmail

I want to develop a app which can get notifications from gmail, twitter and facebook. Something like BlingBoard (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jappka.blingboard&hl=en).

I have started to use the facebook sdk, have done nothing for gmail and twitter yet. Is there any other way to access the notifications or using their api's is probably the only way to go about this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For Email:
Use K9 Client android.

For Facebook: 
Create Broadcast reciever to recieve notifications.

For Twitter :
Same.